# Watermark using background package in beamer

Tags: beamer, backgrounds, watermark

Is it possible? Doesn't work for me with the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
    placement=center,
    scale=1,
    contents={DRAFT}
}

\begin{document}
\frame{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special, nor to quit using the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package; due to the way frames are built in `beamer`, you simply have to add the background material to the appropriate template:

```
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\BgMaterial}
```

this is exactly what the `\BgMaterial` command was designed for. A little complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
    placement=center,
    scale=4,
    contents={DRAFT},
    opacity=1
}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\BgMaterial}

\begin{document}
\frame{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @Gonzalo, your answer work for me. But the watermark doesn't overlays over the block, exampleblock and alertblock environment. What code we have to add?

Answer (score 6):

It is better to use `beamer`s facilities for this job. The text can be placed with the help of `tikz`. Remember that this needs 2-3 compilation runs to settle down since we are using `remember picture` option.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[anchor=north west,scale=3] at ([shift={(1in,-1in)}]current page.north west) {Draft};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\frame{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Too bad we have to learn one set of tools and tricks for articles and another one for presentations.

Comment: @DenisBogdanas You don't have to learn two different set of tools and tricks. You can easily use the `background` package with `beamer` too; see my answer.