# beamer background content top-right

Tags: beamer, positioning, backgrounds, watermark

How can I place a background image in `beamer` at a certain distance from the top and right page margin?

So far I only managed to control the horizontal position:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
{   
\setbeamertemplate{background}{
  \vspace{1in}
  \hspace{1in}
  \Huge DRAFT
}
\frame{\lipsum[1]}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Ideally, the distance should be specified from the top and right corner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a rule of `1in` height and `0in` width and another with `1in` width and `0in` height.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
  \rule{0in}{1in}%
  \rule{1in}{0in}%
  \Huge DRAFT
  }
\frame{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There is always a possibility of using `tikz` to put things on a page byt here only light weight things are considered.

One sample with `adjustbox` package

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{
  \begin{adjustbox}{raise=-1in,right=2in}
  \Huge DRAFT
  \end{adjustbox}
  }
\frame{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to replace \hspace with something that counts the distance from the right? I tried right alignment, didn't work.

Comment: @DenisBogdanas Yes. Use `\rule{1in}{0in}%` instead of `hspace`.  See the edit. Those `%` at the end are needed to prevent spurious spaces.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to count the distance from the right with `right=\paperwidth-0.1in`

Answer (score 4):

Inside a `picture` environment, you can place things a arbitrary positions using `\put`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

{   
    \setbeamertemplate{background}{
        \begin{picture}(254,190.5)(0,0)%
            \put(42,72){% Adjust these coordinates
                \Huge DRAFT%
            }%
        \end{picture}
    }

    \frame{\lipsum[1]}

}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is also possible using `background` package, according to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244141/65072):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
        placement=top,
        position={\paperwidth-0.7in,-0.2in},
        scale=1,
        opacity=1,
        contents={\Huge DRAFT},    
}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\BgMaterial}

\begin{document}
\frame{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]