# Background package in beamer: individual frames

Tags: beamer, backgrounds

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/244091/48787) provides a solution for putting the same background image in all slides. Is there a way to use the `background` package for individual slides?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
scale=40,
color=lightgray,
opacity=0.4,
placement=center,
angle=0,
contents={i}%
}
\BgThispage

\begin{document}
\frame{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy to do with beamers on mechanisms:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

{
    \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image}}
    \begin{frame}
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In exactly the same way the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244141/36296 can be modified:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
    placement=center,
    scale=4,
    contents={DRAFT},
    opacity=1
}

\begin{document}

{
    \setbeamertemplate{background}{\BgMaterial}
    \begin{frame}
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am interested in the `background` package because it gives several options.

Comment: @blackened works just the same with https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244141/36296

Comment: That's my point. I'm wondering I can use the `background` package AND be able to have control slide by slide. (Or, in this case, frame by frame.)

Comment: @blackened Yes, use `\setbeameryemplate{background canvas}{...}` inside a group with the frames for which you wnat it to change.