# Remove white border in Frankfurt theme headline

Tags: beamer, themes, border

I am using the Frankfurt theme with an aspect ratio of 16:10. Using a font size smaller than 11pt, there is a tiny white border that appears in the headline:

[image: Example]

In the figure it is visible above "Section 1". Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}{title}
asd
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: It looks like a bug in the theme. A quick and dirty solution could to add some black line to the top. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244091/watermark-using-background-package-in-beamer.

Comment: I was hoping for something cleaner but it definitely does the job, thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Comment: I can't replicate the issue...