# Watermark using background package doesn't work in Xepersian

Tags: beamer, backgrounds, xepersian, watermark, draftwatermark

I tried to add watermark to my beamer using the followng (that can be found in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/244091/241755))

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
    placement=center,
    scale=4,
    contents={DRAFT},
    opacity=1
}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\BgMaterial}

\begin{document}
\frame{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

and works very well. But when I add `xepersian` package it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum, graphics}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
    placement=center,
    scale=4,
    contents={DRAFT},
    opacity=1
}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\BgMaterial}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\setsansfont[Scale=1.2]{Arial}
\settextfont[Scale=1.2]{Arial}
%\setdigitfont{Arial}
\setmathdigitfont{Arial}
\setmainfont{Arial}


\begin{document}
%\setbeamertemplate{background}{\BgMaterial}
\frame{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

I have tried to set backcolor using `\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}` and it worked but it prints the content twice top of each other.

Another problem is that it has bad output for Arabic and Persian texts. For example it prints "خداوند" as "خ‌داو‌ن‌د".  Same problem happens for `draftwatermark`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beamer has its own background mechanism, no need for the `background` package.

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[font=\fontsize{64}{72}\selectfont,rotate=30,red!40] at (current page.center) {خداوند};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\setsansfont[Scale=1.2]{Arial}
\settextfont[Scale=1.2]{Arial}
\setdigitfont{Arial}
\setmathdigitfont{Arial}
\setmainfont{Arial}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\lipsum[1]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. Easy and simple. Two issues: 1- How to change its typeface? 2- How to bring it to the front of blocks (foreground and not background).

Comment: 1) make whatever typeface changes in `font=...`

Comment: 2) if you want it in the foreground you can use `\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[font=\fontsize{64}{72}\selectfont,rotate=30,red,opacity=0.3] at (current page.center) {خداوند};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}{}`

Comment: I tried to change font by defining `\setfontfamily{\titlefont}{font name}` then using it in `font=\titlefont` (for `tikzpicture` and / or for `\node`) but nothing happened!

Comment: `font=\titlefont` works fine for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcKnd.png Maybe you could ask a new question showing the complete code you tried?

Comment: that is not working for me. I put the font inside `\node ... {\titlefont DRAFT}` and now it is working.